# PHP Date("G)" how to make midnight not equal to 0

Tags: php, date, datetime, redirect

I've got a redirect script meant to not redirect between certain times. I'm using Date("G"), but if I use this for say 12:30, it won't work because I believe 030 is read as 0 and not 30. Will a seperate statement like `if $hour = 0 {$hour = $hour + 1}` and then writing `$milTime` as 130 work? If so, is this the best way? If not, what will work?

Here's an example of a time block that won't read correctly.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
        $hour = date("G");
        $min = date("i");
        $milTime = $hour . $min ;

        if($milTime < 030 || $milTime > 045)
        {
        header('Location: http://havetowatchit.com/watchit.php');
        exit();
        }
?>
```

Comment: In php, integers starting with `0` are considered octal. So `030` is really `24` and `045` is really `37`. You would likely want to convert the number to something like "seconds (or minutes) into the day" and compare with that. Or use a proper timestamp or even a date/time object.

Comment: Also, just do `$milTime = date("Gi");`

Comment: I had no idea about that. Ok, so I can just convert to octal and all is well. Thanks @JonathanKuhn

Comment: I would suggest just getting a timestamp for the suggested date/time you want to look for. It is simple with strtotime. `$time = time(); if($time < strtotime('0030') || $time > strtotime('0045')){ /* do something */ }`

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver I had no idea that would work!

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I've been reading all I can about strtotime, but I don't think I'm ready to use it. It's over my head, thanks though.

Comment: You pass in a string that represents a date and or time and it returns a unix timestamp. The timestamp is just the number of seconds since `1-Jan-1970 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to get rid of your leading zeroes. As mentioned above, [numbers starting with zero](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) are interpreted as octal. But with PHP's [dynamic typing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025361/1255289), string "030" (half past midnight) can be treated numerically as 30:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $time = "030";
php > var_dump($time < 40);
bool(true)
php > var_dump($time > 20);
bool(true)
php > var_dump($time > 40);
bool(false)
```

So your code can look like this:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $time = date("Gi");
    if($time < 30 || $time > 45) {
        header('Location: http://havetowatchit.com/watchit.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```