# Why do I have to write like this? I'm studying python

Tags: python

I'm studying python. And I'm a beginner.
Reading a book, I came to look at this code.

```py
for num in range(101):
    print('Hello ('+str(num)+')')
    num = num + 1
```

It's the result of this code...

```
Hello (0)
Hello (1)
Hello (2)
.
.
.
Hello (99)
Hello (100)
```

Is the code below necessary?

```py
print('Hello ('+str(num)+')')
```

I don't understand why there's `+str(num)+`.

Comment: Did you try it without the `str`?

Comment: Also, which book did you get this code from? You need to throw it away as soon as possible - and destroy it first so that no one else can see it.

Comment: Best thing to do when you have questions like that is to change the code and see what happens.

Comment: Python is *strongly-typed* language meaning that there are restrictions on intermingling, among others you must not add string (`str`) to integer (`int`). Also I suggest taking look at *string formatting* (python has many ways to do this) which allow you to place numbers inside string without need to explicitly call `str`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an int (or a numeric) to a string. Thus, once you print a string (here 'Hello'), you only can add a string (or a char) to that word, so you use str(num) to convert num to a string.

```
num = 3
'Hello' + str(num) => 'Hello 3'
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `str()` transforms `num` into a string. Then, the strings are concatenated using the `+` operator, and then printed.

A modern and elegant way to do this would be to use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
for num in range(101):
    print(f'Hello ({num})')
```

will produce the same result.

---

Side-note : you do not need to do `num = num + 1` : `num` is already automatically incremented in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Python, internally, keeps track of your types, which means that the types you use are tracked by python itself without you needing to explicitly declare them. What you are doing by using `print('Hello ('+str(num)+')')` is saying to the computer: "print on the screen the following value";
but since there is no sum operation between strings and numbers, you need to convert your number into a string, which is what you are doing by using `str(num)`.
This constructs for you a string from the given number; so what you are doing is practically making the value `3 as a number` become the value `'3' as a string`;
then the previous line of code, when `num == 3`, is equivalent to:

```py
print('Hello (' + '3' + ')' )
```

which of course now is about a bunch of operations between strings, that are now accepted; [here is some more information about python's types handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025353/is-python-a-weakly-typed-language-as-variables-can-switch-types).

Also, check the answer by Louis-Justin Tallot which provides a solution using f-strings (where f stands for format) that allows you to use the `f'{variableName}'` syntax, evaluating the value between the curly brackets directly to a string.