# Static created fragment in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I trying to load a static created fragment (right mause, add, fragment, blank fragment) in a framelayout. The app allways crashes....

When i do Fragment `fr = new Fragment;` and load the fr into the FrameLayout the app don't crash.....

The created Fragment is still default.

The code i use to load the fragment into the Framelayout is:

```
BlankFragment foo= new BlankFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fr_overview, foo).commit();
```

This is my framelayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_overview"
    android:id="@+id/fr_overview">
</FrameLayout>
```

I know there are a lot of questions simular like this but i cant find a question which uses "static created fragments" (maybee better described by a Fragment Activity ?)

** ------------- UPDATE ---------- **

Sorry ... my logcat:

```
02-24 16:57:49.991 12801-12801/aaeu.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: aaeu.app, PID: 12801

java.lang.RuntimeException: aaeu.app.presentationlayer.MainActivity@ff4af29 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
at aaeu.app.presentationlayer.BlankFragment.onAttach(BlankFragment.java:84)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1019)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

And the fragment

package aaeu.app.presentationlayer;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import aaeu.app.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting? Can you post the logcat please.

Comment: Could you add the error you get in `LogCat` when your app crashes to your question please?

Comment: Can you show your Fragment class as well. More specifically the onAttach method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your error log, your `MainActivity` class needs to `implement` `OnFragmentInteractionListener`. Your class declaration will need to look something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

Comment: This works!, thanks but what does the onFragmentInteraction method then? where i use this for?

Comment: @RoDo You would typically use an interface like this so that the `Fragment` can communicate with the `Activity` it's attached to - another one of my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449146/hot-to-change-the-text-of-a-parents-textview-inside-a-fragment/33449231#33449231) goes into it :)