# Are booleans mutable in python?

Tags: python, django, boolean

I have the following code in python:

```
def update(request, id):
  success = 0

  try:
    product = Mattress.objects.get(id=id)
    success = 1
  except Mattress.DoesNotExist:
    pass

  if success == 1:
    return render_to_response("success.html")
  else:
    return render_to_response('failure.html')
```

Is this code a valid way to check the "success" boolean. If the code passes through the try statement, will "success" be changed to 1 or is it remaining at 0?

Comment: There are no booleans in your code, nor are you mutating anything.

Comment: There are a number of issues with this snippet.

Comment: I have multiple try-except blocks which is why I'm not returning within the try-except block. What would be the correct way to implement this boolean functionality I need?

Comment: @goelv: 1. There are no booleans in your code. None. 2. You are not mutating anything; you are assigning `success` a *completely new value`.  That is not mutation. I suggest some reading on the subject.

Comment: I wonder where the id you are using is coming from

Comment: @César: written on the fly, I'd hope.

Comment: it's pretty clear you mean `success = False` and `success = True` instead of `0` and `1`

Comment: @goelv, I provided an answer to your question. I think you should update the title of the question. May I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answering your question:

> Are booleans mutable in python?

Yes and no.  Variables that are assigned a boolean value are (probably always, and definitely in this case) mutable, yes.  They're also not restricted to being assigned boolean values, as variables are not staticly typed.

But the booleans `True` and `False` themselves are not mutable.  They are singletons that cannot be modified.

Looking at your actual code:

```
if success = 1:
```

Is not valid syntax, you want a `==` there.  Also, idiomatically speaking you should not use `0` and `1` for success and failure values you should use `True` and `False`.  So you should refactor to something like this:

```
def update(request):
    success = False

    try:
        product = Mattress.objects.get(id=id)
        success = True
    except Mattress.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    if success:
        return render_to_response("success.html")
    else:
        return render_to_response('failure.html')
```

Comment: thanks for the help! quick question for clarification / sake of learning, does "success=false" need to be included at all?

Comment: *Yes* (though with capital F as in the example). Every variable has to be assigned to before its value is checked.

Comment: @goelv yes, otherwise you'll get a `NameError` for failures because you'll be trying to inspect the value of a variable that has yet to be assigned to

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2351203/216356 for a better understanding of typing terms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `success` will be changed to 1 on success.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with this snippet.

1. Firstly, you're not using a boolean type.  Python's booleans are `True` and `False`.
2. Second, you're not comparing in your if statement.  That line isn't valid in Python 3.  What you're looking for is: `if success == 1:` or `if success == True:`
3. You would still be able to assign a boolean value to a variable regardless of boolean immutability.  I believe they are stored as a primitive type, so they're as immutable as any other primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using an actual boolean and not an integer. You can set `success` to `true` or `false` and Python will interpret them as keywords to the values of 1 and 0. Using numbers can be a bit tricky as some languages interpret things different. In some languages 0 is `false` but any value besides 0 is considered `true`. However the answer to your question is yes, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the question you are asking is not even related with the problem you are trying to solve. I think there is a a Pythonic way to achieve what you want by:

```
def update(request):
    try:
        product = Mattress.objects.get(id=id)
    except Mattress.DoesNotExist:
        template_name = 'failure.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'success.html'

    return render_to_response(template_name)
```

Basically if the exception is thrown, i.e., the template you will render will be 'failure.html'. On the other hand, if the query is performed successfully, 'success.html' will be rendered.