# How can I prove that a boolean is immutable?

Tags: python

When learning datatypes in Python, we learn that booleans are also immutable objects. How can I prove this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are booleans mutable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908795/are-booleans-mutable-in-python)