# IF condition in JavaScript - what happens behind the scene

Tags: javascript

I have found out that in JavaScript it is possible to use bare string in *if* condition. I mean something like this:

```
var condition = "";
if (condition) {
    //we will never come here 
}
```

However, it feels very weird for me because, for example, in Java this code would not compile. I try to understand what is happening with this string behind the scene, but fail for now.

Could you explain to me what happens in this case?

P.s. Moreover, if the variable *condition* is not initialized at all then it is still fine and the result will be the same. Feels that JavaScript allows quite a lot of these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem, I also come from a strong typed background. The Javascript concept here is `truthy` or `falsy`.

What is to understand here is that Javascript uses type coercion, so the verification of

```
if (condition) {}
```

where `condition` was initialized a string, will lead to `false`.

As per definition: *A falsy value is a value that translates to false when evaluated in a Boolean context.*
Example of falsy values:

```
if (false)
if (null)
if (undefined)
if (0)
if (NaN)
if ('')
```

Have a read on the [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/truthy) [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in Javascript to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not strongly typed. In this instance this means that the interpreter takes the variable and tries as hard as he can to convert that to a boolean. This means that the integer 0, null, "" and "0" (and I think undefined as wel) all get converted to false, while the integer 1, "1" and non-null objects all get converted to true.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript convert `""` string to boolean which is `false`

Check [equallity and comparision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Check about language:

[Static/Dynamic vs Strong/Weak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351190/static-dynamic-vs-strong-weak)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript  **if(condition)**, the condition is an **expression** that will finally converted to **boolean** type, the language defined that `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`, `0`, `''` will all be casted to boolean **false**, you can check using `!!` operator to explicitly convert to boolean, check:

```
!!'' === false
!!0 === false
!!null === false
!!undefined === false
!!NaN === false
```

all the above expression is **true**, besides,

```
''==0
null==undefined
```

The above expression also is **true**

So, in your condition, `''` == `0`, and will be casted into **false**

That's the magic of javascript, and it's have been used widely.