# PostgreSQL function with table and column names as parameters,and would return min and max of that column (any type) as an array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, function, polymorphism

I am trying to make a function in PostgreSQL, which would take a name of a table and a name of one column in that table (in varchars); and return an array which would have minimum and maximum values of that column.

In advance I do not (want to) know the type of the column, ie. type of the elements in the return array.

I've tried to create a function with polymorphic anyarray as a return type, but keep hitting syntax errors. Have tried both in SQL and in PLPQSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION minmax(tablename character varying, columnname character varying, OUT minmaxa anyarray) AS
$function$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT array_agg(foo) AS %s FROM (
            (SELECT min(%s) AS foo FROM %s)
            UNION
            (SELECT max(%s) AS foo FROM %s)
    ) AS foobar'
       , columnname
       , columnname, tablename
       , columnname, tablename)
   INTO minmaxa; 
END
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The string from the FORMAT would be:

```
SELECT array_agg(foo) AS columnname FROM ( 
  (SELECT min(columnname) AS foo FROM tablename)
  UNION
  (SELECT max(columnname) AS foo FROM tablename)
 ) AS foobar
```

Then test case:

```
create table example (columnA int, columnB varchar);
insert into example (columnA, columnB) values (1, 'ac'), (2, 'ab'), (3, 'aa');

select minmax('example', 'columnA');
select minmax('example', 'columnB');

select array_agg(columnA) from (
   (select min(columnA) AS columnA from example)
   UNION
   (select max(columnA) AS columnA from example)
  ) AS foobar;
```

Should return:

> {1,3}
>   {'aa','ac'}
>   {1,3}

But currently function definition gives:
"SQL Error [42P13]: ERROR: cannot determine result data type
  Detail: A function returning a polymorphic type must have at least one polymorphic argument."

I can make it work, by defining a dummy function parameter 'foo':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION minmax(tablename character varying, columnname character varying, foo anyelement, OUT minmaxa anyarray)
```

(Note. A function parameter foo is not used in function body anywhere.)

And now giving a dummy typed value of the correct type of returning array when calling the function:

```
select minmax('example', 'columnB', ''::varchar);
select minmax('example', 'columnA', 0::int);
```

**Then it works, but what should be changed to I would not need that dummy function parameter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with the standard polymorphic types, but you could do this with jsonb.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION minmax(tablename regclass, columnname character varying)
RETURNS JSONB AS
$function$
DECLARE
  minmaxa jsonb;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT jsonb_agg(foo) AS %I FROM (
            (SELECT min(%I) AS foo FROM %I)
            UNION
            (SELECT max(%I) AS foo FROM %I)
    ) AS foobar'
       , columnname
       , columnname, tablename
       , columnname, tablename)
   INTO minmaxa;
   RETURN minmaxa;
END
$function$
STABLE
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


-- Test with integers
CREATE TABLE test (a int);
insert into test (a) values (1), (2), (3);
select minmax('test'::regclass, 'a');
 minmax
--------
 [1, 2]
(1 row)


-- Test with timestamps
create table test2 (a timestamp);
insert into test2 values ('2012-01-01T00:00:00'), ('2015-01-01T00:00:00');
select minmax('test2'::regclass, 'a');
                     minmax
------------------------------------------------
 ["2012-01-01T00:00:00", "2015-01-01T00:00:00"]
(1 row)
```

I used regclass instead of string for the tablename to help find the correct table according to your search path.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not possible to easily get rid of that attribute you call `foo`. As I understand from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/extend-type-system.html) the value passed as `foo` parameter is required to tell Postgres what the return data type would be.

> **38.2.5. Polymorphic Types**
>
> Five pseudo-types of special interest are anyelement, anyarray, anynonarray, anyenum, and anyrange, which are collectively called polymorphic types. Any function declared using these types is said to be a polymorphic function. A polymorphic function can operate on many different data types, **with the specific data type(s) being determined by the data types actually passed to it in a particular call**.
>
> Polymorphic arguments and results are tied to each other and are resolved to a specific data type when a query calling a polymorphic function is parsed. Each position (either argument or return value) declared as anyelement is allowed to have any specific actual data type, **but in any given call they must all be the same actual type**.

So how I understand this is that with polymorphic function removing attribute `foo` is not possible and your function seems to be such since it uses pseudo-type `anyarray`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing and pointing (and confirming) that out. 

I was wondering if PostgreSQL-"language" or if SQL-language overall is "dynamically/static typed" and "strong/weak typed". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351190/static-dynamic-vs-strong-weak

"Polymorphic arguments and results are tied to each other and are resolved to a specific data type **when a query calling a polymorphic function is parsed.**"