# meaning of type in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I want to know what is meaning of this is:

```
export type VSelect = VTextField & {
   reset: () => void;
   clearableCallback: () => void; 
}
```

so I want to know meaning of this type specially reset: `() => void`

Comment: @Gabriel Heming
what is benifet of use this type with reset: () => void;
I tried to understand the usage of it

Comment: The benefit is the [strong typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351190/static-dynamic-vs-strong-weak) definition. The usage is that you are defining the parameter `reset` as a `function` that has no parameters and returns `void`. So, when using it, you have to pass a function on `reset` and `clearableCallback` parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A type is declared this way:

```js
export type TypeName = {
   property1: type,
   property1: type,
   property1: type,
   /** ... */
}
```

So here, `() => void` is the type of a `function` that doesn't have any parameter, and is returning `void`.

So you can suppose that the `reset` function is like that:

```js
const reset = function (): void {
   /** some code */
}
```

Hence, you can do the same way with whatever you like, eg:

```js
const getUserById = function async (userId: string): Promise<User | null> {
   /** some code */
}

export type UserService = {
  getUserById: (userId: string) => Promise<User | null>
}
```