# Does Python being a loosely typed programming language make it less secure?

Tags: python, java, django

We have this huge issue as a team in choosing a programming stack to develop a web application for a client, one group prefers Django, while the other prefer Springboot claiming that python is a loosely typed programming language, and that makes it less secure unlike Java.
In terms of security is Java better than Python?

Comment: Security as a concept is vastly more complicated. Typing systems have something along the lines of (depending how you count) 4 dimensions, 'loosely typed' is a bit of a cavalier description to then hang highly subjective things such as 'less secure' on. It's more about how e.g. tools can (in the case of java) / can't (in the case of python) do static analysis, and how static types affect how you program. It is necessarily a subjective discussion as to how this affects security, if at all.

Comment: Any team that makes such a sweeping oversimplification as 'java has less loose typing than python therefore it is more secure therefore the team that prefers python can go pound dirt' is ironically indicative of the kind of thinking that leads to security issues. There's nothing for it, I'm afraid: Y'all are going to have to talk about your different preferences and figure it out like adults.

Comment: In fact, Python and Java are >both< strongly typed, and that (arguably) makes them more secure that weakly typed languages like C and C++ ... which allow buffer overruns, random clobbering of memory, etc.  The difference between Java and Python is that Java is primarily *statically* typed, and Python is *dynamically* typed.  (You can do kind-of-dynamic typing in Java too.)  But zwitserloot is right.  You guys need to do your own analysis and come to your own (hopefully rational) conclusions about what languages to use.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351190/static-dynamic-vs-strong-weak

Comment: Also note that strong vs weak is relative and nuanced.  And so is static vs dynamic.  And that makes these terms (even) less useful when when trying to use them to infer security properties.