# Advantages to Languages with "Weak Typing"

Tags: types, strong-typing, weak-typing

Why would a programming language want to use weak typing over strong typing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323323/can-someone-tell-me-what-strong-typing-and-weak-typing-means-and-which-one-is-bet

Comment: Since the terms "weak typing" and "strong typing" do not have a generally agreed upon definition, this question is basically meaningless and thus un-answerable until the OP provides a precise definition.

Comment: Why don't you try using the common definition or use your own definition.  Don't be so pedantic.

Comment: Could you update with the common definition of weak typing?

Comment: As I already explained to you in the comment directly above yours: *there is no common definition*. You might just as well have asked "Why would a programming language want to use flurblr over brnksar", because those two words are about as meaningful as "weak typing" and "strong typing". There is a generally agreed upon definition for static/dynamic, implicit/explicit, sound/unsound, safe/unsafe and structural/nominal/duck typing. There is currently a consensus being formed about what latent/manifest typing means. But nobody knows what "strong" or "weak" typing means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very basic level, it'll also make it easier for beginners to pick up. (Probably one of PHP's reasons for success, irrespective of whether you appreciate PHP or not.)

That said, the general erosion of sound operational knowledge of memory management, pointers, etc. is a bit of a worrying trend, if only because you can't always stand on the shoulders of giants. (Someone still has to write microcode, high performance device drivers, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is supposedly in development time.  It allows programmers to spend less time considering and typing out variable types when writing code.  Whether or not this offsets the potential increase in mistakes and difficulty understanding the code when you don't know what type a variable is supposed to be, well, that's a question unto itself.

Another reason is that it makes certain kinds of polymorphism easier to deal with.  Given a function that takes two arguments and adds them, there's no need to specify them both as `int` or even as some interface `addable`.  If the `+` operator can handle the combination of the two args, then it just works.

Comment: Not all static type systems have explicit type signatures everywhere. Some have type inference. And most of the ones that do can also infer the type of polymorphic values. So what you say is more false than true IMHO.